# What is the advantage of using asynchronous controllers in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What are the advantages of using Asynchronous controllers in my ASP.NET MVC website?
Please explain using simple terms; I am not a .NET expert

Comment: Short answer: To make your website more responsive. If your users are stuck staring at a blank screen while your server is processing a bunch of stuff, they will decide your website is broken and leave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the documentation says it in pretty simple terms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

> The AsyncController class enables you to write asynchronous action
>   methods. **You can use asynchronous action methods for long-running,
>   non-CPU bound requests. This avoids blocking the Web server from
>   performing work while the request is being processed.**

Working URL : [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: Can you provide an example of "long-running, non-CPU bound requests"? Action methods are meant to return, how can they be made async when they need to complete their work before the server returns a `ViewResult`?

Comment: @Omar An example long-running, non-CPU bound request would probably be something like a dynamic news aggregation website that returns the headlines from 10 popular news websites: if your average response time is .5 seconds for each website, it would take 5 seconds to complete... with async controllers it can be done in about ~0.5 seconds. There could be **many** other examples, some are more suitable than others. I'm not an MVC expert, but as far as I understand the `ViewResult` blocks until all 10 async events have completed... you can get more details in the article I linked in my answer.

Comment: My async article you quote is ancient. Please refer to http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4 which provides links to this question.

Comment: @Lirik - you're making the classic mistake of confusing parallelism with asynchrony. There is some overlap, but they're not the same.

Comment: @Omar - Asynchronous actions do not return a response until all processing has been done.  What makes them asynchronous is that when you perform an async request and it goes off and does something (ie a web request or database access) the action can give up it's thread pool worker so that it can service other users requests.  Once the work has been completed, a new thread pool worker is started to complete the rest of the request processing.  which (if there are no further awaits) eventually returns the response back to the client.  Async actions scale better, and let the server work better